# MongoDB array of objects, count by some simple condition and group by object key

Tags: mongodb

I have a bunch of reports from VirusTotal and thought to myself: "in order to create the statistics I need, why not put the data into a MongoDB and simply query it. Can't be too hard, now, can it?"

Well, it can. Here's the basic data format.

[image: data format]

I'm mostly interested in the `scans` array. Unfortunately the scanner name is a key of an object and since I'm by no means even a MongoDB novice, I have no clue how to approach this. Hell, I don't even know how to search on Google.

What I'd like to do:

- Get a count of how many scanners have `detected:true` (and `false`), grouped by the name of the scanner. For example something like this (for the `true` search):

  ```
  Bkav: 20000
  TotalDefense: 19238
  BitDefender: 39132
  ...
  ```
- Another interesting bit would involve the `result` field. It contains the name of the malware and I'd like to create a statistic how many scanners use the same malware-family name for a specific file and for the whole collection.

I'd really appreciate some examples or pointers. I'm on the verge of writing a little python script that scans all the JSON files and does what I need instead of using MongoDB.

Comment: Try to post your sample collection and the output... Images don't work here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get from the objects to arrays, you can use [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) (Mongo 3.6 and newer):

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
    {$project: {scans: {$objectToArray: '$scans'}}},   // object -> array
    {$unwind: '$scans'},                               // array -> multiple docs
    {$match: {'scans.v.detected': true /*or false*/}}, // filter
    {$group: {_id: '$scans.k', count: {$sum: 1}}}      // group
])
```

It will result in something like this:

```
[{
    "_id" : "TotalDefense",
    "count" : 1.0
},
{
    "_id" : "Bkav",
    "count" : 3.0
}]
```

As for the second question: [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) works also with objects, so you can group by `{scanner: '$scans.k', result: '$scans.v.result'}` for example.

Comment: That did help a lot, thank you. Follow-up question: Why is it `$scans.k` in the `$group` section and `$scans.v`  in `$match`. It's the `k` and the `v` that make me wonder.

Comment: Just look into the `$objectToArray` documentation. Basically, it makes an array of `{k, v}` objects, where `k` are the keys and `v` - values. We want to group by the scanner, so the key of this object, but filter by one of the values.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Now it makes sense. Thank you very much.